# Image does not scale

Tags: html, css

First, I want to state that I am not a web designer, but I am trying to search for solutions.
At the moment I am at loss, as I cannot figure out why a logo I am trying to add on a footer does not scale with resolution.
In fact, it is displaying it in full resulation only.
There is another logo in the footer that is scaling when resolution changes.

When I paste the code in TryIt, it is working, but once I put it on server, the image is in full resolution always.

Here is the TryIt link - https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GRDOYEDNJX5K

As tyou can see, here the code would work.

What I have done is defined the image in footer.php

```
                        <div class="logo5">
                        <img src='https://i.ibb.co/42Lgdw7/8a2403c4b0d344d5ae7c3762c74fddb4-0001.jpg' class="logo5">
                        </div>
```

And added to CSS these lines

```
.logo5 {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

This is the rest of _footer.scss file

```
    .footer-wrapp {
  background-image: url("../../images/footer_back.jpg");
  background-position: top;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  .container {
    width: 100% !important;
    max-width: unset !important;
  }
  .additional-info {
    padding: 30px 0;
    @media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
      padding: 30px 0 15px;
    }
    h4 {
      color: #fff;
    }

    p {
      color: #7d7d7d;
    }
  }
  #myFootNavWrapp {
    margin: 60px 15% 0;
    @media screen and (max-width: 1600px){
      margin: 60px 5% 0;
    }
    @media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
      margin: 0;
      padding-left: 0;
      padding-right: 0;
      justify-content: space-between;
    }
    @media screen and (max-width: 520px) {
      align-items: flex-start;
      padding-top: 25px;
    }
    a {
      color: #6377a4;
      margin-right: 20px;
      &:hover {
        text-decoration: none;
        border-bottom: 2px solid $main__red;
      }
    }
    .mobile-logo-wrapp {
      display: none;
      margin-left: 20px;
      @media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
        display: inline-block;
      }
      a {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 45px;
        height: 45px;
        background-image: url("../../images/logo.jpg");
        background-size: contain;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center;
      }
    }
    #navFoot {
      border-radius: 10px;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      @media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
      }
      .customFootNav {
        flex-grow: 1;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        list-style-type: none;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        width: 100%;
        @media screen and (max-width: 520px) {
          flex-direction: column;
          align-items: flex-start;
          justify-content: flex-start;
        }

        li {
          flex-grow: 1;
          min-width: 5%;
          a {
            color: $main__dark_blue;
            border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
            transition: all 0.2s linear;
            font-weight: 600;
          }
          &:hover {
            a {
              text-decoration: none;
              border-bottom: 2px solid $main__red;
            }
          }
        }
      }
      .privacyFootNav {
        flex-grow: 1;
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
          display: flex;
          flex-direction: row;
          list-style-type: none;
          flex-wrap: wrap;
          width: 100%;
        @media screen and (max-width: 520px) {
          flex-direction: column;
          align-items: flex-start;
          justify-content: flex-start;
        }
        @media screen and (min-width: 520px) and (max-width: 788px) {
          margin-left: 92px;
        }
          li {
            flex-grow: 1;
            min-width: 5%;
            a {
              color: #6377a4;
              border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
              transition: all 0.2s linear;
              font-weight: 400;
            }
            &:hover {
              a {
                text-decoration: none;
                border-bottom: 2px solid $main__red;
              }
            }
            &.current-menu-item {
              a {
                text-decoration: none;
                border-bottom: 2px solid $main__red;
              }
            }
          }
      }
      .additional-wrapp {
        flex-grow: 1;
      }
      .custom-menu-logo {
        position: relative;
        height: 95px;
        min-width: 200px;
        @media screen and (max-width: 1500px) {
          min-width: 175px;
        }
        @media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
          min-width: 150px;
        }
        @media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
          min-width: unset;
          width:90px;
          margin-right: 20px;
        }
        @media screen and (max-width: 520px){
          display: none;
        }
        &:before {
          content: '';
          width: 100%;
          height: 100%;
          position: absolute;
          left: 0;
          top: 0;
          margin: 0 auto;
          background-image: url("../../images/Logo_Red.jpeg");
          background-position: center;
          background-size: contain;
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
          transition: all 0.2s linear;
        }
        a{
          outline: none;
          display: block;
          z-index: 9999;
          position: absolute;
          width: 100%;
          height: 100%;
        }
        &:hover {
          border: none;
          a {
            border: none;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is there anything that would interfere with the logo I am trying to add to not scale?

Thank you.

Comment: There are factors that cannot be accounted for unless you are able to copy the HTML ***after*** the page has loaded by `right-click>inspect` (using Chrome). What you have posted at that TryIt link is incomplete, because PHP dynamically adds more elements and classes to the page which isn't rendered until the page is loaded (in general). Also, the styles posted is preprocessor CSS, you'll get more help if you convert that into CSS (this [online tool](https://jsonformatter.org/scss-to-css) should help). Also, read this section on [mcve].

Comment: Despite what I previously mentioned, try adding a copy of the ruleset `&:before {...}` and add it after it. then change`:before` with `:after` and inside the `{...}` change the `background-image: url(https://i.ibb.co/42Lgdw7/8a2403c4b0d344d5ae7c3762c74fddb4-0001.jpg)` and change `left:0` to `right:0`. That's just a guess based on the fractured info provided. Also, avoid using `#id` use `.class` and suffix it with a number if you really need it to be unique.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that you're using wordpress, I already had problems while customizing themes and files this way, because wordpress theme sometimes overwrite your style and that's is bad.

To avoid it, I needed to put the css `!important` property, this way you force your style over any other that not have this property.

Maybe it's not the best appraoch, but worked for me, you should give a try.

```css
.logo5 {
  width: 100% !important;
  height: auto !important;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Forgot to mention, that I tried that at one point but without success. Tried one more time, just to be sure, but without changes.
Here I will show visualy what I am trying to achieve:
*This is where I want the logo to be. The red blured logo changes dynamicly, I want the new logo to do the same.
https://imgur.com/a/NhiuWTf

*This is what happens
https://imgur.com/a/gKp9zpp